# Winter Bash 2018 icon disappeared

Tags: bug, winter-bash-2018

EDIT: I feel this question fits better on meta.stackexchange, so I'll "transfer" it and delete from here within minutes.

After I clicked on the Winter Bash icon, instead of showing the hats notification screen the icon just disappeared:

[image]

Now it's missing on all the Stack Exchange sites.

If that matters, the icon showed a number on it (one new hat) before I clicked on it.

Also I'm sure I didn't click the link "I hate hats" at the bottom of the Winter Bash notification screen.

Comment: Looks like it doesn't handle the current load too well ...

Comment: Global warming is real. The icon can't withstand the heat. It has melted.

Comment: @yivi perhaps his CPU got too hot? Try cleaning your fans.

Comment: Before deleting it here, include a link to the meta questions, for the 10k users out here

Comment: Those minutes feels like forever! Maybe it's because of the hat!

Comment: FWIW, for me the iccon appears with some delay (< 1 sec) when loading a page.